# How to use jquery css('display', 'block') and css('display', 'none') in if else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to use jquery-circle-progress (https://github.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress) start animate when user scroll in to that location. I was able to do a little bit with bug. Problem is the animation keep repeating. I like to animate it only once when user scroll to that location. Here is my work:

jquery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
var windowWidth = $(this).width();
var windowHeight = $(this).height();
var windowScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#circle').circleProgress({
        value: 0.75,
        size: 180,
        fill: {
            gradient: ["lightblue", "grey"]
        }
    });
});


if (windowScrollTop > 760) {

    $('#circle').css('display', 'block');


} else {
    $('#circle').css('display', 'none');

}
});
```

html:

```
<div id="circle"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#circle {
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Move content of `$(document).ready(function() {});` outside of `$(window).scroll(function() {});`

Comment: Now it is working but my main intention which is to animate with scroll not working.

Answer (score 0):

try

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowWidth = $(this).width();
    var windowHeight = $(this).height();
    var windowScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (windowScrollTop > 760 && $('#circle').is(':hidden')) {
        $('#circle').show('normal', function() {
            $(this).circleProgress({
                value: 0.75,
                size: 180,
                fill: {
                    gradient: ["lightblue", "grey"]
                }
            });
        });
    } 
    if (windowScrollTop < 760 && $('#circle').is(':visible')) {
        $('#circle').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: It works but if I scroll slowly to that point it works like a charm but If I quick scroll then the progress circle slides in to the div which I have no idea why there is an auto slide.